# how can I pass the id and client for OAuth 2.0 authorization?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an authorization function in Google Data Studio. How can I pass the id and client there to make a generic function.
if I change the function as follows: getOAuthService(id, client) and id and client are taken from request.config Params, then the other functions also require these parameters. However, Google Data Studio does not pass the request parameter in the isAuthValid, auth Callback, and get3PAuthorizationUrls functions.

My function now:

```
    function getOAuthService() {
    return OAuth2.createService('exampleService')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize')
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth.yandex.ru/token')
    .setClientId(id)
    .setClientSecret(client)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.OAUTH2)
    .build();
}

/**
 * Resets the auth service.
 */
function resetAuth() {
  getOAuthService().reset();
}

/**
 * Returns true if the auth service has access.
 * @return {boolean} True if the auth service has access.
 */
function isAuthValid() {
  return getOAuthService().hasAccess();
}

/**
 * The OAuth callback.
 * @param {object} request The request data received from the OAuth flow.
 * @return {HtmlOutput} The HTML output to show to the user.
 */
function authCallback(request) {
  var authorized = getOAuthService().handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  };
};

/**
 * Gets the 3P authorization URL.
 * @return {string} The authorization URL.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/authorization-info
 */
function get3PAuthorizationUrls() {
  return getOAuthService().getAuthorizationUrl();
}

function getConfig(request) {
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();
  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
  config.newInfo()
    .setId('instructions')
    .setText('Add ClientSecret и ClientId.');
  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('clientId')
    .setPlaceholder('clientId');

    config.newTextInput()
    .setId('clientSecret')
    .setPlaceholder('clientSecret');
  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
  return config.build();
}

function getSchema(request) {
  var fields = getFields(request).build();
  return { schema: fields };
}

function getData(request) {
    var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
  var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);
  var driveService = getOAuthService();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.webmaster.yandex.net/v4/user', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'OAuth ' + driveService.getAccessToken(),
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome. The included code isn't complete. What do you mean by "generic function"? How do you want to use it? What problems do you have to use it as is?

Comment: please provide the complete code snippet, including libraries you are importing

Comment: Rubén, Aerials i update my post and add more details. generic = universal.